# How to find sum of multiples number equal x. Give a[] as multiple integer and x as expect value

Tags: java, kotlin

How can I change my code to find all possible number combination where addition of number is equal to some input number.

Example data

We have `array [1,4,6,8,9,12,17,19,21,28,45,67,.....,n]`and input number 29

Expect result is 
(Sum of multiple value from array that equal to x)
`[1,28]
[8,21]
[1,9,19]
....`

My current code is

```
int [] number = new int[]{1,5,8,12,15,18,20,24,28,30};
    int expectValue = 25;

    for (int i = 0; i < number.length-1 ;i++){
        for (int j = i+1; j < number.length; j++){
            if(number[i] + number[j] == expectValue){
                System.out.println("["+number[i]+","+number[j]+"]");
            }
        }
    }
```

Result

```
[1,24][5,20]
```

Comment: `How can I create java or kotlin code for solve this issue?` By start making it.

Comment: @Gatusko Thank you for your reply. Yeah i tried but not get solution yet.

Comment: @LiNgKung show you attempt. That's what he meant. Pure coding requests are off-topic on SO. We can help you write you code but not write it for you.

Comment: I believe you are trying to write sudoko. You should check this out [Algorithm for solving Sudoku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697334/algorithm-for-solving-sudoku)

Comment: @Goion Hi, I updated my code on topic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding all possible combinations of numbers to reach a given sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632322/finding-all-possible-combinations-of-numbers-to-reach-a-given-sum)

Answer (score 0):

Here is some basic code to get you started. It only covers the case where two numbers sum to the target value.

```
 public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int[] precursors = {10,20,30,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
        Arrays.sort(precursors);
        int target = 12;

        for (int i = 0; i < precursors.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < precursors.length; j++)
            {
                if (precursors[i] >= target)
                {
                break;
                }
                else if (precursors[i] + precursors[j] == target){
                    System.out.println("[" + precursors[i] + "," + precursors[j]+ "]");
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: Had you ran that? I'd bet there are some flaws in that code ;-)